# using both trap and exec to redirect output to tee in bash

Tags: bash, exec, trap

I have script that reads lines from a file, processes each line. I'd like to be able to do some "post-processing" in a way that even when the script didn't finish reading all lines because I pressed Ctrl+C it would still do the post processing. To achieve this I'm trying to do both of the following:

1. redirect stdout to a file; Later do the post-processing from that file, however I'd like to see what's going on, so I'd like to redirect to "tee"
2. trap Ctrl+C and do the post processing there

I managed to make either 1 or 2 work, but not both at the same time:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 2. Either this works 
# trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
trap ctrl_c INT
function ctrl_c() {
    echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"
}

# 1. Or this works    
LOGFILE=/tmp/${FILE}.tee
rm ${LOGFILE}
exec > >(tee ${LOGFILE}) 2>&1

function post_process() {
    # use ${LOGFILE}
}

egrep "(${URL_PATH})" ${FILE} |
    while read LINE ; do
        #...
    done

post_process
```

Comment: Not sure I understand WHERE you're stuck. What if you add `post_process` to the `ctrl_c` function and use the `tee` redirection for the `while` loop only?

Comment: It sounds like a good idea. How do I do the redirection only for the while?

Comment: @Gavriel with `exec 3>&1 >output; ...; exec >&3`. But please read my answer -- you do **not** have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ignore the `^C` / `SIGINT` in the post-process function:

```
preprocess(){
   yes baa
}
postprocess(){
   sed 's/a/z/g'
}
preprocess | { trap '' INT; postprocess; sleep 1; echo DONE; }
```

When you run that pipeline and press `^C`, `preprocess` will be killed, but `postprocess` will continue running until all the output produced by `preprocess` has been consumed.

Notice that the `trap '' INT` (with an empty string as the handler) will also ignore `SIGINT` in the subprocesses; do not replace it with eg. `trap 'echo INT trapped' INT` because that will cause any `sed`, etc. to be killed too by '^C', despite the signal being handled in the parent process.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Note: pre-process prints to stdout and I'd like it to keep showing what's it's doing + write to a file, that's why I'm trying to use tee. I don't find where to put "exec > >(tee ${LOGFILE}) 2>&1" or something similar, because anywhere I try it it causes the trap not to work

Comment: `preprocess | tee logfile | { trap '' INT; postprocess; }`   ---or--- `preprocess | { trap '' INT; postprocess | tee logfile; }`

Comment: Thanks. This works for me: trap ctrl_c INT ; preprocess | tee logfile ; postprocess